# How do actors cry in movies?

Tags: film-techniques

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What techniqes are used by directors to make an actor cry?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/993/what-techniqes-are-used-by-directors-to-make-an-actor-cry)

Do actors always have to get in the mood to cry? Are their teardrops always real? What techniques are used to help actors in such scenes?

Comment: I answered this question a while back, here: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/993/what-techniqes-are-used-by-directors-to-make-an-actor-cry